# Search and replace in evil mode

Tags: evil, text-editing

I'm an emacs newbie and am using evil mode for text formatting. I have some text in the following format:

```
word1 = meaning with elaboration; word2 = simpler meaning; word3; word4 = much long explanation needed;
```

and want to wrap each of word1, word2, word3 etc.. into `\textif\textbf{word1}}`, `\textif\textbf{word2}}` etc. and transform the original text as

```
\textif{\textbf{word1}} = meaning with elaboration;
\textif{\textbf{word2}} = simpler meaning;
\textif{\textbf{word3}};
\textif{\textbf{word4}} = much long explanation needed;
```

In VIM, I verified separately that the following search+replace pattern applies the changes for `word2`, `word3` and `word4` (I know this pattern won't change `word1`)

`:%s,;\s*\(\w*\),; \r\\textit\{\\textbf\{\1\}\},g`

However, this doesn't work in emacs. All I see is **Ex: Syntax error**

Does vim-style search+replace work in emacs? Is there a way to apply the same search+replace in emacs?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, neither from my fully customized Emacs setup nor from a minimal Evil setup (run `make emacs` inside a Git checkout of Evil, decline running tests, `C-x b foo.tex`, `M-x tex-mode`, insert the text above, execute the ex command above). In both cases I see "[No match]" and upon executing the commands, I get no replacements. Ensure you're using the latest version and provide a minimal set of reproduction instructions.

Comment: Also consider that you have the choice between using Emacs-flavored regex (fast, verbose) and Vim-flavored regex (slow, buggy). Consider using the former to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evil's vim-style search-replace does work, but you have to modify it slightly:

`:%s/; \(\w+\)/;\n\\textit{\\textbf{\1}}/g` will perform the replacement you want (this won't affect word1, but you've already mentioned that).

You have to use `/` to separate the `s`, match, replacement and the global `g`.

`\s*` [doesn't match](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46062/whitespace-and-newlines-in-regexps) the whitespace characters as expected.

Comment: Can someone show me the emacs-way to achieve the same? I've tried 'M-x regex-replace` with a few regular expressions but haven't found a solution yet. My replace-regex `;[:space]+[^[:space]+]` doesn't work